# Wordpress - Post meta filed (post sticky check box and excerpt ) in save post hook in $_REQUEST

Tags: php, wordpress

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OSpY.png)

I'm not getting info in $_REQUEST wordpress save_post
and update meta data  action .

I want to check is this post sticky checked box value changed or update . 
and also check post excerpt is changed .

---

i add function in function.php

```
function custom_post_meta($post_id){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
}
add_action('update_post_meta','custom_post_meta'); 


function check_values($post_ID){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
}

add_action( 'post_save', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

get nothing ....

---

im using wpml how can i check in post is in not English or in other language 
like hindi .

Comment: Please add your form including checkbox into your question

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST in the place of $_REQUEST

Comment: First i tried  with $_POST ... 

in which hook i got check box value ??

Comment: update hook you can use first but if you create a new post ad save value then you get value inside save_post hook it totally dependent on your need.

with the help of post id and key of your meta box you can get
post meta 
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )